# Share files between stages in Gitlab CI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

Hello i have a pipeline.

I have also 2 script in my code deploy_terraform.sh et deploy_ansible.sh.

For now i want that it do only 2 things:

```
stage deploy-dev-terraform
stage deploy-dev-ansible
```

In the first stage it creates ssh keys on the runner and launch a script that creates infrastructures in GCP for my app, several vm, network, …

In every VM it copies the ssh keys created on the runner so that they possess metadata, and so i can create a connexion with ansible later.

In the second stage i want to create the file inventory.ini and connect to my vm with ansible so that i can configure the servers.

My problem is : When i do 2 stages for thos 2 scripts, the problem is that stages in runners are not persistant, so when i want to connect with ansible the elements are no longer present in the second stage, so the pipeline in the seconde stage go on errors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But when i put all of this in one stage i have no problem.

[image]

[image]

How to keep persistance between the 2 stages?

```
default:
  tags:
    - default_gitlab_runnerrunner_test

stages: 
  - deploy-dev-terraform
  - deploy-dev-ansible
```

```
#_________ ETAPE 1 - Déploiement des VM sur GCP via terraform pour l'environement de dév __________#
deploy_dev_terraform:
  stage: deploy-dev-terraform
  image : ubuntu-personalise
  before_script:
    - ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" -N ""
    - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=.secure_files/credentials1.json
  script:
    - mkdir ./environment-dev/private  
    - cp .secure_files/credentials1.json ./environment-dev/private/credentials1.json
    - export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/builds/$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN/projet_app_devops/environment-dev/private/credentials1.json
    - cd ./environment-dev/scripts
    - echo "Déploiement sur l'environnement de développement"
    - chmod +x deploy_terraform.sh
    - ./deploy_terraformdeploy_terraform.sh
    # - chmod +x deploy_ansible.sh
    # - ./deploy_ansible.sh

#_________ ETAPE 2 - Configuration des serveurs VM via ansible __________#
deploy_dev_ansible:
  stage: deploy-dev-ansible
  image : ubuntu-personalise
  dependencies:
    - deploy_dev_terraform
  script:
    - cd ./environment-dev/scripts
    - echo "Configuration des serveurs VM via ansible"
    - chmod +x deploy_ansible.sh
    - ./deploy_ansible.sh
```

I dont know what to do to resolve this, using one stage solve this but it is not the good way.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know what to do to resolve this, using one stage solve this but it is not the good way.

You confused "stages" and "jobs". When it did work for you, it wasn't because you got rid of the second [stage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stage), but because you did both in a single [job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/).

Scripts you run in the same job ***share*** a single workspace. All files generated by the first script are still visible to the second script.

Scripts that run in different jobs each start with a blank, isolated workspace by default.

The mechanism to share files between workspaces is artifacts. The first job needs to declare which files shall be exported as [`artifacts`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html), and the second job needs to declare that it [`needs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) the artifacts from the first job.

You did not declare *any* artifacts, so *nothing* was preserved from your first job.

Of course this requires *you* to know which files are used to communicate between scripts. You do not want to capture the *whole* workspace, as you are going to be charged a lot for accidentally capturing whole build folders including temporary files.

Also, for your own sanity's sake: Do not rely on the default behavior of Gitlab where artifact imports are done on the stage granularity level, pulling in ***everything*** from ***all*** jobs in the previous stage. Always make explicit use of the `needs` keyword in job to tie jobs explicitly together, you will eventually have more complex pipelines where you need to keep  your artifacts isolated between the different processing chains.